# How to change answer key in dictionary?

Tags: python

I have this kind of data, there is lacking of inconsistency. I might need to choose a few IDs. May I know the easier way in python?

this is the kind of data that i have.

```
dd = [
    {
        "id": "abc",
        "age": "23",
        "response": [
            {"QID": "2a", "answer": "a"},
            {"QID": "2b", "answer": 2},
            {"QID": "2c", "answer": 1},
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": "cde",
        "age": "20",
        "response": [
            {"QID": "2a", "answer": "b"},
            {"QID": "2b", "answer": 2},
            {"QID": "2c", "answer": 2},
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": "dfe",
        "age": "21",
        "response": [
            {"QID": "2a", "answer": "a"},
            {"QID": "2b", "answer": 3},
            {"QID": "2c", "answer": 4},
        ],
    },
]
```

I want to change all QID 2b and 2c. Actually there's 10 IDs that need to be changed. 
I would like to change from 1 to A, 2 to B, 3 to C and 4 to D.

```
dd = [
    {
        "id": "abc",
        "age": "23",
        "response": [
            {"QID": "2a", "answer": "a"},
            {"QID": "2b", "answer": "b"},
            {"QID": "2c", "answer": "a"},
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": "cde",
        "age": "20",
        "response": [
            {"QID": "2a", "answer": "b"},
            {"QID": "2b", "answer": "b"},
            {"QID": "2c", "answer": "b"},
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": "dfe",
        "age": "21",
        "response": [
            {"QID": "2a", "answer": "a"},
            {"QID": "2b", "answer": "c"},
            {"QID": "2c", "answer": "d"},
        ],
    },
]
```

I'm kind of new to python. Sorry for not giving any code that I have a try. since I get an error message in reading the QID.

Comment: But you can post the code. It doesn't have to be correct or run without errors. We're here to help.

Comment: You can (and should) include both the code and the full error message in your question; see [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

If you want to limit the changes to specific values and specific questions, you can simply iterate through the dictionary and check if what you want to change matches both conditions then change the value when desired. The part that says `resp['answer'] in changes` will look in the `changes` dict keys by default.

```
changes = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
questions_to_fix = ('2b', '2c')

# Iterate through each quiz
for record in dd:
    # Loop through each question/response
    for resp in record['response']:
        # Check that the question ID is one you want to update and that the
        # answer is something you want to convert.
        if resp['QID'] in questions_to_fix and resp['answer'] in changes:
            # Lists and dictionaries are mutable, so you can change it in place
            resp['answer'] = changes[resp['answer']]
```

Below is the output of `print(dd)`

```
[
    {
        "id": "abc",
        "age": "23",
        "response": [
            {"QID": "2a", "answer": "a"},
            {"QID": "2b", "answer": "b"},
            {"QID": "2c", "answer": "a"},
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": "cde",
        "age": "20",
        "response": [
            {"QID": "2a", "answer": "b"},
            {"QID": "2b", "answer": "b"},
            {"QID": "2c", "answer": "b"},
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": "dfe",
        "age": "21",
        "response": [
            {"QID": "2a", "answer": "a"},
            {"QID": "2b", "answer": "c"},
            {"QID": "2c", "answer": "d"},
        ],
    },
]
```

If you realize that you don't need to limit it to specific questions, you can leave out the part where you're validating the question id is one that you want to fix. You can also use the `dict.get(key, default)` syntax to pull changes from the `changes` dict if it's available.

```
changes = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}

for record in dd:
    for resp in record['response']:
        resp['answer'] = changes.get(resp['answer'], resp['answer'])
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much! Do you know how if we have QID like 2Ea, 2Ca, or 2Ba for different responses but the same question? Only the middle one is different. I try to put 2*a but it did not work.

Comment: The answer I would give in that case largely depends on how varied your `QID` values get. The simplest would be `if resp['QID'][0] + resp['QID'][-1] in questions_to_fix and resp['answer'] in changes:` That way the questions are identified as the first and last characters in the id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you tried, but could you give this code a chance ?

```py
# _*_ coding:  utf-8 -*-

dd = [
    {
        "id": "abc",
        "age": "23",
        "response": [
            {"QID": "2a", "answer": "a"},
            {"QID": "2b", "answer": 2},
            {"QID": "2c", "answer": 1},
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": "cde",
        "age": "20",
        "response": [
            {"QID": "2a", "answer": "b"},
            {"QID": "2b", "answer": 2},
            {"QID": "2c", "answer": 2},
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": "dfe",
        "age": "21",
        "response": [
            {"QID": "2a", "answer": "a"},
            {"QID": "2b", "answer": 3},
            {"QID": "2c", "answer": 4},
        ],
    },
]

for element in dd:
    for r in element["response"]:
        if r["QID"] == "2b" or "2c":
            if r["answer"] == 1: 
                r["answer"] = "A"
            elif r["answer"] == 2: 
                r["answer"] = "B"
            elif r["answer"] == 3: 
                r["answer"] = "C"
            elif r["answer"] == 4: 
                r["answer"] = "D"

print(dd)
```

This should do the work, updating your dictionary with the correct values when the keys you look for are encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
for obj in dd:
    for i in obj["response"]:
        if i["QID"] in ("2b", "2c") and i["answer"] in (1,2,3,4):
            i["answer"] = ["a", "b", "c", "d"][i["answer"]-1]

print(dd)
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives your expected output:

```
import string


def map_value(val):
    # create dict of 1 -> a, 2 -> b, etc.
    mapper = {n+1:i for n, i in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)}
    return mapper.get(val, val)

# dd is your data
for i in dd:
    for entry in i["response"]:
        # overwrite dict value
        entry["answer"] = map_value(entry["answer"])
```

Comment: I like the clever use for `string.lowercase`, but just a heads up when it comes to performance, you're generating a dict with 26 elements every time you want to change an answer. Using Jupyter to time the function, your current code runs in 30.5 microseconds, but dropping the function and changing your last line to `entry["answer"] = mapper.get(entry["answer"], entry["answer"])` runs in 5.28 microseconds with the given dataset. Also, `string.lowercase` has been removed in python3 and should be `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Comment: @cohan yes fair enough i didn't think about performance for this, taking `mapper` out of the function is a good idea. I didn't know that had been renamed in python3, i'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code which making replacement:

```
for dict1 in dd:
    response = dict1['response']
    for resp in response:
        if resp['QID'] in ['2b','2c']:
            if resp['answer']==1: resp['answer']='a'
            elif resp['answer']==2: resp['answer']='b'
            elif resp['answer']==3: resp['answer']='c'
            elif resp['answer']==4: resp['answer']='d'
```